# Does the shorthand ternary operator make multiple calculations?

Tags: ternary-operator, conditional-operator

The ternary operator has a shorthand version, i.e.

`var = exp ?: exp2`

I know it works in PHP. Other languages may have also picked it up. C# has similar functionality (for the context of this question) - `??`.

When the condition passes, is the expression evaluated again, or is the result stored somewhere?

Comment: Wait, so what language is the question about?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

`The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.`

It is stored, not computed twice.

Comment: True, I suppose it shouldn't be compared. What about the original operator referred to?

Comment: In PHP however the expression is evaluated every time, so for example: php -r "echo rand(0, 1) ?: -999;"
this will print -999 many more times. That is because expr1 ?: expr2 returns expr1 not the result of the expression.

Comment: you seem to be contradicting yourself, you wrote it returns expr1, but prints -999?